Formatting using addstyle in openxlsx package
Question 1
In the code below, while performing the run, all the outputs is displayed in RStudio console.
This particularly happens if the code add style is in the loop for different workbook tabs. I have used sapply.
i would want this to run silently without displaying anything in console.
Question 2
Is it possible to not display the worksheet name in the console when creating the workbook tabs using loop/sapply.
library(openxlsx)
set.seed(2)
dat = data.frame(v1=LETTERS[1:10], v2=runif(10), v3=letters[1:10], v4=runif(10))
wb = createWorkbook()
sapply(paste0("Data",1:10),function(x){addWorksheet(wb,x)})
pct = createStyle(numFmt="0%")
sapply(paste0("Data",1:10),function(x){writeData(wb, x, dat)})
sapply(paste0("Data",1:10),function(x){addStyle(wb, x, style=pct, cols=c(2,4), rows=2:(nrow(dat)+1), gridExpand=TRUE)})
saveWorkbook(wb, "my_workbook.xlsx")


One way is to assign the unwanted output to an R object:
wb = createWorkbook()
x <- sapply(paste0("Data",1:10),function(x){addWorksheet(wb,x)})

x <- sapply(...)
x <- sapply(...)

And you can combine those 3 sapply calls in to one:
foo1 <- function(data) {
  wb = createWorkbook()
  
  x <- sapply(paste0("Data",1:3), function(x) { 
    addWorksheet(wb, x) 
    pct = createStyle(numFmt="0%")
    writeData(wb, x, data)
    addStyle(wb, x, style=pct, cols=c(2,4), rows=2:(nrow(data)+1), gridExpand=TRUE)
  })
  
  saveWorkbook(wb, "my_workbook.xlsx", overwrite = FALSE)
}


Actually my original code is quite big. I have to import multiple xlsx files and the output is also multiple workbook with many tabs. I am trying to keep minimum objects in R. Does that seems good or should I create as many objects?. will it interfere with the speed and performance?

You can reduce those 3 sapply calls to just 1 if speed is an issue. And my code only creates one object, "x". And if you put it all into a function, "x" is not saved when the function ends.

I dont know for what reasons, the above code did not save any workbook. no error was displayed. Anyways Thanks I will try creating objects.

Works for me. Maybe check the working directory again? getwd().

Another option is to use a for() loop construct instead of sapply since you don't want to save the results.
